# How to consume service Using Resttemplate.exchange

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, resttemplate

> I want to make a service call using Resttemplate.exchange method:
> See the below is my service to which i want to consume:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/service", consumes = { "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" })
    public ServiceObligationResponse retrieveServiceObligationResponsesByServiceObligationRequests(
            @Valid @RequestParam Map<String, String> params,
            @RequestHeader(value = KEY, required = true) String key,
            @RequestHeader(value = ID, required = true) String id,
            @RequestHeader(value = AUTH_HEADER, required = true) String authHeader)
            throws CustomUnAuthorizedException {
 Some code ............... 
}
```

Please help i am new to microservice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add headers and params to `RestTemplate` object.

```
final String uri = "http://localhost:8080/service";

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
headers.set("KEY", "myKey");
headers.set("ID", "myId");
headers.set("AUTH_HEADER", "myAuthHeader");

Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("param1", "value1");

HttpEntity<Map<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(params , headers);

ResponseEntity<MyResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, request, MyResponse.class);

if(response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
  MyResponse resObj = response.getBody();
  // do something with the response
}
```